# How to install Robomongo on Ubuntu?

Tags: system, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and I want to install Robomongo on Ubuntu.

Are there any instructions on how I can I install Robomongo on my machine?

Answer (score 72):

Follow these simple steps.

- Download the robomongo: https://robomongo.org/download
- Extract the .tar.gz downloaded from above
- Change directory to extracted folder.
- You'll find a bin folder. Go in there, then double click on robomongo.

Anytime you'll wanna run robomongo, you will have to do something like this from terminal:

```
/path/to/robomongo_dir/bin/robomongo
```

You might wanna add a link to robomongo from your `/usr/bin` which will allow you to do something like this anywhere from terminal:

for that

- navigate to *robomongo_dir/bin*
- right click on *robomongo* executable file and click on **Make Link**, *Link to robomongo* executable file will be created there
- rename *Link to robomongo* to your wish ( let say **robo_**)
- move this link to */usr/bin* directory with below command on terminal

  ```
  sudo mv /robomongo_dir/bin/robo_ /usr/bin
  ```

Now you can run robomongo from terminal OR from run command (Alt+ F2) by typing `robo_`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ubashu Some get answers or help and sometimes forget where they got the assistance.

Answer (score 60):

Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) is the free lightweight GUI with embedded shell for MongoDB  enthusiasts. Use Ubuntu Software to install the robo3t-snap package or install it from the terminal with:

```
sudo snap install robo3t-snap
```

Comment: this is should be top answer in 2019 and for Ubuntu 18.04 above.

Comment: Be careful, you should copy your private key into `~/snap/robo3t-snap/4` if you wish to do SSH tunelling with the snap package (cf. https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1590#issuecomment-656055534)

Comment: Currently, Snap pkg is outdated. It would not work properly with Mongo Atlas, when you create a user with specific permission for specific DB. You need to work on Robo3t =>1.4.

Comment: Following answer helped to install 1.4.+ Robo3T https://askubuntu.com/a/1317140/860337

Comment: This doesn't keep up very fast with the latest versions, however.

Comment: I installed it but couldnt find its binary

Answer (score 28):

**Notice**:

Now `Robomongo` program become `Robo3T` studio and you can download it from [Here](https://robomongo.org/download).

If you need old version include **Old `Robomongo`** program, you can download version from [Here](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases)

======================= **My answer from 2016**

answer of [@Rexford](https://askubuntu.com/a/781793/214624) is nice But I will be more clear

There Two ways to install `robomongo` program into ubuntu using command line:

**First way**

1.1 download tar.gz file from [Official `robomongo` website](https://robomongo.org/download)(choose version you need to install and get it's tar.gz download file url)

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

1.2 extract tar.gz file

```
 tar -xvzf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

1.3 mv files and folders into the result folder from extraction operation
into folder `robomongo` under `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robomongo
sudo mv  robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo
```

1.4 make sure excute file for `robomongo` program which exists under
`/usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin` folder is excutable file

```
cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin
sudo chmod +x robomongo ## run command only if robomongo isn't excutable file
./robomongo
```

**Second way**

2.1 download deb file from [Official `robomongo` website](https://robomongo.org/download)(choose version you need to install and get it's deb download file url)

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.8.5/linux/robomongo-0.8.5-x86_64.deb
```

2.2 install deb file using dpkg command line

```
sudo dpkg -i robomongo-0.8.5-x86_64.deb
```

2.3 open `robomongo` program using command line by run

```
robomongo
```

**Very Important Notice**:

All available versions 0.8.5 and earlier of `robomongo` have both `deb` file and `tar.gz` file download urls. So If you want a previous version you can use one of two ways But If you need download version 0.9.0 there only one way is the first ones

more links about install `robomongo` program: [link 1](http://trimc-db.blogspot.com.eg/2015/01/mongodb-administration-robomongo-on.html), [line 2](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/MongoDB/MongoDB_Management_Tool_RoboMongo.php), [link 3](http://hackwithin.com/2014/05/13/setup-development-machine/)

Comment: it seems these *.deb files are not unavailable anymore

Comment: to make `robomongo` executable from anywhere, I renamed its folder and `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/robomongodir/bin/robomongo /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: If you follow these instructions and you see  `robomongo: command not found` then you're probably on 32-bit architecture which isn't (and probably won't be) supported by robomongo

Comment: This no longer works. Version 0.8 is now so old, it's incompatible with the current version of Mongo, and Studio3T seems to have stopped releasing deb files for newer versions.

Comment: https://download.robomongo.org is now behind an annoying subscribe wall. Files can also be found here: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases

Comment: @RickyA Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 17):

Robomongo is now Robo 3T:

Download the tar file [from the site](https://robomongo.org/download).

The current file is `robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz` but obviously this may be different to what you downloaded in the future: adapt the commands below accordingly.

Open a terminal and `cd` to wherever you downloaded the archive, eg, `cd Downloads` and `mv` it to wherever you would like to keep it, perhaps `/opt`. Then extract it, and make a symlink from the binary to a PATH location, for example...

```
sudo tar -xf /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t /usr/local/bin/robo3t
```

Now you can run `robo3t` in your terminal and it will work.

Comment: @Zanna sorry didn't see the `/opt` path

Comment: @George my bad, just fixed it after seeing your comment :)

Answer (score 16):

**Install Robo3t On Ubuntu 18.04 / Ubuntu 20.04**

**1- Download the package** form https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases or using `wget`

```
wget https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases/download/v1.4.4/robo3t-1.4.4-linux-x86_64-e6ac9ec.tar.gz
```

**2- Extract here using**

```
tar xvf robo3t-1.4.4-linux-x86_64-e6ac9ec.tar.gz
```

**4- Move the extracted** package

```
sudo mv robo3t-1.4.4-linux-x86_64-e6ac9ec /usr/local/bin/robo3t
```

**Change directory to**

```
cd /usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin
```

**5-** **Download icon**

```
sudo wget https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/site_media/appmedia/2018/09/logo-256x256.png -O icon.png
```

**6-** To make `desktop icon` for `Robo3t`, we can make a file in

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/robo3t.desktop
```

### Paste these and save

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Robo3t
Icon=/usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin/icon.png
Exec="/usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin/robo3t"
Comment=Robo3t 
Categories=Development;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Validate the `.desktop` file:

```
desktop-file-validate /usr/share/applications/robo3t.desktop
```

If everything is correct, you can search in application menu for robo3t.

Now, we can find the `icon` in application launcher menu by search for `robo3t`

We can check [this](https://gist.github.com/LogansUA/53d4a3a60bb3c2aeb031ed6a9e5d0ef4) also

[Reference](https://www.dotnetjalps.com/2018/03/install-robo3t-robmongo-ubuntu.html)

Comment: As of 2019-12-18 Robo 3T v1.3 has a bug that prevents editing in the UI. Upvoted this answer for the URL for v1.2.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

run the folowing commands (feel free to update the links and change folder names):

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/1.1.1/linux/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz -C /opt
rm robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/BKP/
sudo mv /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/BKP/
sudo ln -s /opt/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t /usr/bin/robo3t
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/robo3t.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Robo3T
Exec=robo3t
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
EOL
```

then you will also get a launcher icon so you will be able to press win-key and search for.

But you wont get an image for the icon (some ubuntu place-holder) :(

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam you can also take a look at this script for additional installs
https://github.com/david1asher/post-install-scripts/blob/master/ubuntu.sh

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be sudo apt-get install for robomongo.
There is tar.gz download available from [here](http://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0-rc4/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6.tar.gz)
Once you download that you need to do

```
gunzip robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6.tar.gz
tar -xvf robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6.tar
```

and then either move the untar-ed version to `/opt` (if needed)

Otherwise there is another way as mentioned in this [blog](http://trimc-db.blogspot.com/2015/01/mongodb-administration-robomongo-on.html) or [here](https://gist.github.com/saelfaer/11362946)

Comment: I have done this robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6.tar.gz how i can proceed ?

Comment: Please specify details in terms of what you have done and what error messages(if any) you are getting?

Comment: @SurajMaurya if answer below helped, you mind marking as answer?

Answer (score 1):

To install Robomongo (Robo 3T) version **1.4**+ use following steps

- Download the : https://robomongo.org/download to Downloads folder
- Start command line and paste there following commands:

```bsh
cd ~/Downloads/
tar -xvzf robo3t*.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robo3t
sudo mv robo3t*/* /usr/local/bin/robo3t/
cd /usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin/
sudo chmod +x robo3t
```

Previously, you could install it using Ubuntu Software using `sudo snap install robo3t-snap`.
But it is not updating from version 1.3.

Comment: Link to manual on [how create shortcut for Robo3t](https://gist.github.com/abdallahokasha/37911a64ad289487387e2d1a144604ae)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to install the latest version of **robomobo** that call be now **robo3t**. Or you try to install on ubuntu 16.04 follow the below step and your robomongo install

Download latest robomongo tar file

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/1.1.1/linux/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
```

Extract it

```
tar -xvzf https://download.robomongo.org/1.1.1/linux/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
```

Make a directory

```
mkdir ~/robo-backup
```

Move **robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++** direcotry  to **~/robo-backup/** direcotry

```
mv robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* ~/robo-backup/
```

Run the robo3t

```
robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install mongodb binary (Manually) to your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic). You need to download mongodb .tgz file from this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs#production) .

1) Download it to your ~/Downloads folder and moveit to home directory by typing `mv Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz ~/`

2) Then unter it by typing `tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz` place it here (Home directory /home/). Dont move it from here.

3) Then make a directory at /data/db location and give write permission to thatdirectory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db

sudo chmod -R 777 /data/db
```

4) Now, this is the tricky area. Make sure u r in hme directory by typing pwd (Present Working Directory)

```
pwd
```

it will show

```
/home/<your user name>
```

Then type

`ls -al`

This command will show up all hiddenfile at home directory and search for

`~/.bashrc`

5) Edit the .bashrc file and write

```
export PATH=mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:$PATH
```

and save the file type `source ./bashrc`

Then type `echo $PATH` at terminal it will display `~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:/home/xenon/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

6) Now at terminal type `mongo --nodb`
it will show `MongoDB shell version v4.0.4`

From here , you are all set, go ahead and enjoy mongodb installation. This istallation is bit complex but by this method you can easily control the version of mongodb and use it as per your need.

7) Then start mongod

```
>sudo mkdir -p /var/log && sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log
>mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --logpath /var/log/local.log --fork
>mongo --port 27017
```

Answer (score 0):

My version grabs the latest tar.gz release from github:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
 
set -e

# sudo apt install jq desktop-file-utils

# clean
rm -rf robo3t /usr/localbin/robo3t /usr/share/applications/robo3t/usr/share/applications/robo3t.desktop

JSON="$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/Studio3T/robomongo/releases/latest | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name | select(endswith(".tar.gz")))')"
URL="$(echo $JSON | jq -r '.browser_download_url')"
FILENAME="$(echo $JSON | jq -r '.name')"
NAME="$(basename "$FILENAME" .tar.gz)"
echo "URL=$URL"
echo "FILENAME=$FILENAME"
echo "NAME=$NAME"

curl -sOJLN "$URL"
tar xf "$FILENAME"
rm -rf "$FILENAME"
sudo mv "$NAME" /usr/local/bin/robo3t
cd /usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin
sudo curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Studio3T/robomongo/48f7dfde82b9c4233ca0133044114dca239f5239/install/macosx/robomongo.iconset/icon_128x128.png" -o icon.png
cat > robo3t.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Robo3T
Icon=/usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin/icon.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/robo3t/bin/robo3t
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
StartupNotify=true
EOL

desktop-file-validate robo3t.desktop
sudo desktop-file-install robo3t.desktop
rm robo3t.desktop

# Now, we can find the `icon` in application launcher menu by search for `robo3t`

# https://askubuntu.com/questions/739297/how-to-install-robomongo-on-ubuntu/974766#974766
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987542/is-there-a-link-to-github-for-downloading-a-file-in-the-latest-release-of-a-repo#comment49446532_29360657
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156892/how-to-validate-verify-desktop-files
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value/821419#821419
```

You can find it in github repo https://github.com/rofrol/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/install-robo3t-on-debian.sh